# Rails3 Devise undefined method `confirmation_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rake

I've seemingly set up Devise for my User authentication, with the :confirmable option set.

Everything seems to run fine when I run it in the browser, I sign up, go to the confirmation url shown in the server log in my `rails s` console.

However, when I try to add the following to my db/seed.rb

```
User.create!(:username => 'haar', :email => 'haar@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

And run `rake db:setup --trace`

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<#<Class:0x1062f79a0>:0x1062f6618>
/Users/haar/Dropbox/Websites/TenOutOfTen/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_haml___1737567023_2199377480_0'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render_without_haml'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/haml-3.1.3/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/deprecated_api.rb:111:in `render'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:735:in `collect_responses_and_parts_order'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:750:in `each'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:750:in `each_template'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:745:in `each'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:745:in `each_template'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:731:in `collect_responses_and_parts_order'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:673:in `mail'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb:21:in `devise_mail'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/devise-1.4.5/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:5:in `confirmation_instructions'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `send_action'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:75:in `process'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:471:in `process'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:466:in `initialize'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `new'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/actionmailer-3.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `method_missing'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:50:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `create_or_update'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `create_or_update'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `create_or_update'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:60:in `save!'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:in `save!'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:245:in `save!'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:245:in `save!'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:34:in `create!'
/Users/haar/Dropbox/Websites/TenOutOfTen/db/seeds.rb:7
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:281
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/haar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/haar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/haar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to resolve it?

I have the following line included in my test environment, for the record:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Running on Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.8, with devise 1.4.5.

Comment: Do you see the confirmation_url when you run 'rake routes'? Is it possible it's named something else?

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much, it was listed as user_confirmation in the routes. Strange that devise:views generated something different.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It simply turned out that when I ran `rails generate devise:views`, it generated incorrect paths when compared to the routes `devise_for :user` generated. It also generated some other issues, such as the `user_confirmation_url` pointing to @resource, as the first parameter; when it shouldn't have.

(I didn't want the question to be left unanswered, I'm unsure as to the typical etiquette. If I'm wrong in doing this, please let me know).

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  So... how did you end up fixing it?  I have devise_for :artist in my routes.  I also used generate devise:views; which views need to be fixed?

Comment: Oh I see in views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb needs to change confirmation_url to artist_confirmation_url for me.  Thanks.

Comment: also had to remove @resource as the first parameter as you said, otherwise &format= was being injected into the url causing confirmation link to have error.

Comment: this seems to expect a post request, but in an email you have to use get, right? how did you achieve this

Comment: I'm not sure you should need to do this. As long as you've define the model as :confirmable, and restarted the server, the helpers should work as is.

Comment: Agree with @aceofspades, if you start changing devise-generated files you will mess up things.

Comment: @Bernát The whole point of allowing you to generate the views is so that you can customise and modify them; being able to change something means you can shoot yourself in the foot if you don't pay attention but doesn't mean you shouldn't do it.

Comment: (You are absolutely right to answer your own question when you figure out a solution, if that's what you're asking in the parentheses)

Answer (score 26):

I also had the same issue just doing restart my server do the job for me and this error removed.

just do CTRL + c and then start your server using rails s

Comment: as simple as it could be :D

Comment: Yep, that was the solution. I run the server in a branch that didn't have the devise confirmation configured, so when I checked out the branch that has that, it didn't work until I restart the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an additional, if you're using STI with Devise models, as I am, you can check via the type attribute. So, my code looks like this:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', manager_confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) if @resource.type == 'Manager' %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', subscriber_confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) if @resource.type == 'Subscriber' %></p>
```