# Getting error undefined method `reconfirmable' on a fresh install of rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a fresh install of Rails and devise.

I run:

```
rails g devise:install

rails g devise user
```

I sign up and I navigate to /users/edit and I receive an error

```
undefined method `reconfirmable' for #<Class:0x007ff836033398>

6:   <div class="form-inputs">
7:     <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
8: 
9:     <% if resource.class.reconfirmable && resource.unconfirmed_email.present? %>
10:       <p>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></p>
11:     <% end %>
12:
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.2.2 if not, and do not forget to regenerate views

[Issue on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2212)

Comment: sorry, really did not notice :)

Answer (score 0):

In your users table check if you have the column `:unconfirmed_email`

This column is required by devise,

Or if you are in a fresh installation, just uncomment the following segment in `db/xxx_devise_user_create.rb`

```
## Confirmable
# t.string   :confirmation_token
# t.datetime :confirmed_at
# t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
# t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

Comment: Thanks, so I added the columns but still getting the same error... It seems very strange to me as I've added devise to my rails apps many times and never had to edit the default migration file...

Comment: so is the new columns are migrated?, and in the initilize/devise.rb add config.reconfirmable = true

Comment: yes and yes... User.first returns: => #<User id: 1, email: "new@user.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$4VWrrjmVr0V3nRGd1Jy8qO3kYvkhsc9.vRZI.37AiGNB...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-01-13 00:24:55", last_sign_in_at: "2013-01-13 00:24:55", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-01-13 00:24:55", updated_at: "2013-01-13 00:24:55", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil>

Comment: so in your User model have u added :confirmable :) ?

Comment: and i restarted the server... I tried both   config.reconfirmable = true and config.reconfirmable = false, restarted both times... To be honest, I don't even need confirmations at this point. Should I just be editing the views to remove this reconfirmable logic?

Comment: Ok, I just added confirmable.. New error undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<#<Class:0x007f8ec43e8230>:0x007f8ec77206e8>... I'd honestly like to not use confirmable at all

Comment: this might help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461332/rails3-devise-undefined-method-confirmation-url

Comment: ahhh it was a bug with devise... fixed now: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/0c4615e33741f39a6dd1bfdefbcedc3cd2189af8

Comment: glad you found the solution :D