# Rails 4.0, Issues for email confirmation in devise plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

I am using a devise authentication in rails 4.0.0.
But I am not able to confirm the email, also if I try to create a new user it will show below error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<# <Class:0xbbdb734>:0xbbdadfc>):
  2: 
  3: <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
  4: 
  5: <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource,  :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

When I checked the log, I found confirmation partial is not rendering from current project folder instead it is rendering from,

```
Rendered /home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-3.0.3/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (9.1ms)
```

Devise gem's version is

```
$ gem list devise
devise (3.0.3, 1.4.2)
```

Route is,

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations", :sessions => "users/sessions", :passwords => "users/passwords", :confirmations => "users/confirmations" }
```

Rake routes are given below,

```
$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                                     welcome#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          users/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          users/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         users/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         users/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     users/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    users/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         users/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)         users/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)      users/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  users/registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        users/registrations#new
 edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          users/registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)                  users/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                  users/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                 users/registrations#destroy
   user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     users/confirmations#create
 new_user_confirmation GET  /users/confirmation/new(.:format) users/confirmations#new
                     GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     users/confirmations#show
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461332/rails3-devise-undefined-method-confirmation-url

Comment: it should be `user_confirmation_url(....` not only `confirmation_url`

Comment: I have given like user_confirmation_url(...) but it is not taking, confirmation partial is rendering from different folder (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: I am not getting a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461332/rails3-devise-undefined-method-confirmation-url

Comment: can you please show me what `rake routes` given ?

Comment: Above I have added rake routes

Comment: look at there there is no confirmation but there is  `user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation` so the url should be `user_confirmation_url`

Comment: In project folder(/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb), I have given same path like user_confirmation_url but it is not taking

Comment: look at your error it does not seems that `<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource,  :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>`

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Issue is, folder structure is not correct for /confirmation_instructions.html.erb file.
Thank You.